# Start web scraper from specific aspx page

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from [this](http://forestsclearance.nic.in/Online_Status.aspx) webpage. It is a big job -- there are ~600 next page links, and the scraper breaks down after 300 pages (8 hours) because of a "connection reset by peer" error.

Rather than starting fresh after each crash, I want the scraper to start at page 300 and hopefully it will reach the last page without error and I can append the two outputted data files. My code (below) works when I go through the pagination consecutively (starting at page 1), but it doesnt work if open page 1 and try to post to page 300. I get an error about the page_no variable "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' " which implies it never reached page 300. Any ideas what the issue is and how to solve it?

```
#Open Search Page
url = 'http://forestsclearance.nic.in/'            
r = requests.get(url + 'Online_Status.aspx')
VIEWSTATE, GENERATOR, VALIDATION = getFormData(r.content)
cookies = {
    'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'kaqs1jzegnfn4zxpwio4jthl',
    'countrytabs': '0',
    'countrytabs1': '0',
    'acopendivids': 'Omfc,Email,Campa,support,livestat,commitee,Links',
    'acgroupswithpersist': 'nada',
}
headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
}
#Click Search box
r = requests.post(
    url + 'Online_Status.aspx',
    headers=headers,
    cookies=cookies,
    data = {
        'ctl00$ScriptManager1': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button1',
        '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
        '__EVENTTARGET': '',
        '__VIEWSTATE': VIEWSTATE,
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': GENERATOR,
        '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': '',
        '__EVENTVALIDATION': VALIDATION,
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlyear': '-All Years-',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddl1': 'Select',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddl3': 'Select',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlcategory': '-Select All-',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DropDownList1': '-Select All-',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtsearch': '',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HiddenField1': '',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HiddenField2': '',
        '__ASYNCPOST': 'false',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button1': 'SEARCH',
    }
)
VIEWSTATE, GENERATOR, VALIDATION = getFormData(r.content)

#Post to Page 300
lastPage = 563
for page in range(300, lastPage + 1):
    r = requests.post(
    url + 'Online_Status.aspx',
    cookies=cookies,
    data = {
    'ctl00$ScriptManager1': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button1',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$RadioButtonList1': 'New',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': 'Page${}'.format(page),
    '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdevents',
    '__VIEWSTATE': VIEWSTATE,
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': GENERATOR,
    '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': '',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION': VALIDATION,
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlyear': '-All Years-',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddl1': 'Select',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddl3': 'Select',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlcategory': '-Select All-',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DropDownList1': '-Select All-',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtsearch': '',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HiddenField1': '',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HiddenField2': '',
    '__ASYNCPOST': 'false',
        }
    )

    #scrape data
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', {'id' : 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdevents'})
    page_no = int(table.find('tr', {'class': 'pagi'}).span.text)
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
    for row in rows[1:len(rows)-2]:
        #My scraping code goes here...

    #Get form data for next page post request
    VIEWSTATE, GENERATOR, VALIDATION = getFormData(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like `table` (and probably `soup`, and maybe `r.content`) isn't the object you're expecting it to be (null?).  Have you tried dumping the response headers on that request?  If you can show us the results of `print(r.headers)` before you load your `soup` variable, we may be able to help you dig further.

Comment: Thanks. The important part of r.content prints: Invalid postback or callback argument. &nbsp;Event validation is enabled using &lt;pages enableEventValidation=&quot;true&quot;/&gt; in configuration or &lt;%@ Page EnableEventValidation=&quot;true&quot; %&gt; in a page. &nbsp;For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. &nbsp;If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: That looks like the server is taking issue with some part of your request.  My guess would be that the session that you made the first 300 requests with is no longer valid after the connection reset. Taking a step back, you might consider hitting those pages with separate threads or some other asynchronous mechanism to try to consume all 600 before the timeout kicks in.